# Can anyone explain why this behaviour might be happening in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms

I'm developing a Windows Forms Application. See attached image for the Interface[image: App]. Now I've put a close button (X) in the Panel(say Panel2) which has Application Constants as label.The first combo box is in another panel(say Panel1). Now when I click on the X button in Panel 2 I want the Panel to be invisible and the combo box text to be blank. Simple enough.
So I write

```
Panel2.visible=false;
comboBox1.SelectedIndex=-1;
```

When I click on X, the text in combo box goes blank, then I have to click again for the Panel2 to go invisible.

Then I changed the sequence

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex=-1;
Panel2.visible=fasle;
```

and this works smooth. Not sure why this might be happening? Is there anything that I might be doing with my form design/code to have such a behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged handler in the application?

Comment: You probably have code that makes the panel visible again.  Set a breakpoint on it.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you have an event handler on comboBox1 for SelectedIndex changed, which makes the panel visible for some reason.  Moving the setting of selectedindex before the hiding of the panel fixes this.